# Add element to array setState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-hook-form, react-state

I have useState "setAnswers" (set) and "answers" (get) (answers is array with strings)
and click trigger:

```
onClick = () => {
    setAnswers((prev) => [...prev, e]) 
    setValue(questionKey, answers)
    console.log(watch(questionKey))
}
```

but with ever click i got only previous value

Comment: to example with first click i got empty array, and with second click - only one element

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your console.log is execute before the state finish to be calculated, if you put your console.log  on an other place, normally, you find what you want.

Try it, and say me

Comment: I tried,
i still get previous value
(console.log now is on end of onClick function)

Comment: Put the console.log on the render with {}

Comment: All results saving with react-hook-form, and submitting form returning same

Comment: not works, result is array without last value

Comment: Can I see your state declaration ?

Comment: const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<string[]>([])

Comment: ok, I don't see you use react hook form (that explain the watch), say me if Gabriel answer work, if not, I check it later. Sorry, for my bad

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log(watch(questionKey))` all time will go wrong on `onChange`.

you need use a `useEffect` to log or make anything else with state as base.

```
    useEffect(() => {
     console.log(watch(questionKey)
    }, [questionKey]);
```

to more info you can read here:
https://dev.to/mpodlasin/react-useeffect-hook-explained-in-depth-on-a-simple-example-19ec

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little bit confused: `watch` function from `useForm` is used to

> Watch specified inputs and return their values.

So `console.log(watch(questionKey))` does make no sense.

`watch` should be used in this way:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) => console.log(value, name, type));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch]);
```

You use a `useEffect` to subscribe/unsubscribe watch on some form fields, and then in component's body you could call:

```
const watchSomething = watch(<something>);
```

and, every time the field called `<something>` will change his value, `watch` will execute `console.log(value, name, type)`.

If you want to print the very last value of a state variable, you should know that `setValue, setAnswer` are async functions and its absolutely not guaranteed that on next line you could log the last value.
To solve your problem you have 2 choices:

1. use `watch` correctly;
2. forget `watch` and use classic `useEffect`:

   ```
   onClick = () => {
      setAnswers((prev) => [...prev, e]) 
      setValue(questionKey, answers)
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(questionKey); //<-- here you will print the very last value of questionKey
   }, [questionKey]);
   ```

[Here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) a guide on how to use `watch`.